# animate a circle inside canvas when hitting the space bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am trying to do this little game that when the player start hitting the space bar a couple of circles start to animate and float.
The player win the game when all the circles enter the `stands` here is my jsfidle :http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/S62b5/

I having a bit of problem to animate the circles with a floating effect when hitting the space bar can anyone lead me for a way to start or give me a small example

```
function updateCanvas() { 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

All your code is good, however the question you are asking is like implementing complete logic, basically you should change the x and y co-ordinates of the circle on space bar hit.

However which circle to change and how are you going to implement the logic is completely your call. How are you going to consider the amplitude of animation so that the player skills are tested?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd start by declaring your circles globally.

Then, I'd move defining their position from outside of their drawing function.

Finally, set up an interval to control their position over time. Make it call updateCanvas after your repositioned them, which would in turn call the drawing functions again (after clearing the canvas, of course).